# Как присвоить текст элементу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
mixin filter-date-dropdown(params)
  .filter-date-dropdown
    .filter-date-dropdown__caption
      h3= params.leftCaption
    .filter-date-dropdown__input.input__style
      p.filter-date-dropdown__text Выберите даты
      span.filter-date-dropdown__expand-button.material-icons expand_more
    .dropdown-date__date-picker.dropdown-date__date-picker_hidden
      include ../filter-date-picker/filter-date-picker
      +filter-date-picker()
```

пробую

```
let isDateDropdownText = this.offsetParent.previousElementSibling.firstChild;
console.log(isDateDropdownText);
isDateDropdownText.text('text');
```

получаю ошибку

```
Uncaught TypeError: isDateDropdownText.text is not a function
```

console.log(isDateDropdownText); - выводит нужный элемент, но поля innerHTML, innerText и textContent у него пустые

возможно есть конфликт с кодом плагина air-datepicker

```
clear: function () {
  this.selectedDates = [];
  this.minRange = '';
  this.maxRange = '';
  this.views[this.currentView]._render();
  this._setInputValue();
  if (this.opts.onSelect) {
    this._triggerOnChange()
  }
},
```

заменил

```
.filter-date-dropdown__input.input__style
  p.filter-date-dropdown__text Выберите даты
  span.filter-date-dropdown__expand-button.material-icons expand_more
```

на

```
input.filter-date-dropdown__input.input__style.filter-date-dropdown__text(type='text' placeholder='Выберите даты' readonly)
```

работает, оставлю пока так, наверно, плагин работает только с инпутом

Comment: вы бы для удобства какой-нибудь минимальный html код добавили бы для лучшего понимания :)

Comment: добавил для лучшего понимания

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что `this` и `this.offsetParent.previousElementSibling.firstChild` - это не jQuery-обьекты, а HTML-DOM-обьекты. У него нет метода `.text()`.

Попробуйте так:

```js
let isDateDropdownText = this.offsetParent.previousElementSibling.firstChild;
let $isDateDropdownText = $(isDateDropdownText);
console.log($isDateDropdownText);
$isDateDropdownText.text('text');
```

Кстати, название переменной с jQuery-обьектами принято начинать с знака доллара.
Согласитесь, так понятнее что переменная содержит именно jQuery-обьект а не просто елемент или любое другое значение.

Comment: теперь в консоль выводит Object { 0: p.filter-date-dropdown__text, length: 1 } вместо <p class="filter-date-dropdown__text"></p>, но текст при этом всё равно не меняется

Comment: Ну теперь как минимум точно jQuery-обьект

Comment: Можете показать html код или скинуть ссылку на codepen?